# Discard last batch (or add some entries) in training and validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, batchsize

I have split my data in training and validation samples (80% for training and 20% for validation):

```
Total_Samples = 1147
Training_Samples = 918
Validation_Samples = 229
```

But, i am facing a problem of dimension error related to the last batch of my data being smaller than the `batch_size` i have defined to my problem. Say i use a `batch_size = 32`, you can see the last batch of both training and validation data will be smaller than that. I have created a python generator to supply those batches, like this:

```
def power_data_generator(batch_size,gen_type=''):
    while 1:
        df_input_train=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_target_train=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_input_valid=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_target_valid=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        for chunk, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4 in zip(df_input_train,df_target_train,df_input_valid,df_target_valid):
            X_train = chunk.values
            X_train = np.resize(X_train,(batch_size,24,2,1))
            Y_train = chunk2.values
            X_valid = chunk3.values
            X_valid = np.resize(X_valid,(batch_size,24,2,1))
            Y_valid = chunk4.values
            if gen_type =='training':
                yield (X_train[0:batch_size],Y_train[0:batch_size])
            elif gen_type =='validation':
                yield (X_valid[0:batch_size],Y_valid[0:batch_size])
            elif gen_type =='inference':
                yield X_valid
```

Is there any command i can add to just ignore the last batch if it is smaller than the `batch_size` i have defined (or add some entries to it to make it exactly equal my `batch_size`)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you put a `chunksize=batchsize` argument in the `read_csv` function.

Let's say `batch_size=32`.

This makes pandas give you 32-sized data frames. 
But at the end it gives you the rest.

Then you try to reshape the X_train :

- `X_train = np.resize(X_train,(batch_size,24,2,1))`

The probleme must come at the last chunk.

I think  try + except could resolve it.

You can try to reshape and break the for loop if it raise an exception.

```
def power_data_generator(batch_size,gen_type=''):
    while 1:
        df_input_train=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_target_train=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_input_valid=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        df_target_valid=pd.read_csv('some arguments')
        for chunk, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4 in zip(df_input_train,df_target_train,df_input_valid,df_target_valid):
            X_train = chunk.values
            ######################
            try:
                X_train = np.resize(X_train,(batch_size,24,2,1))
            except:
                break
            Y_train = chunk2.values
            X_valid = chunk3.values
            try:
                X_valid = np.resize(X_valid,(batch_size,24,2,1))
            except:
                break
            #######################
            Y_valid = chunk4.values
            if gen_type =='training':
                    yield (X_train[0:batch_size],Y_train[0:batch_size])
            elif gen_type =='validation':
                yield (X_valid[0:batch_size],Y_valid[0:batch_size])
            elif gen_type =='inference':
                yield X_valid
```

You may want to reshape according to the number of line resting and yield the rest.

Comment: The (batch_size, 24, **2**, 1) reshaping implies you add a third dimension and i'm not understanding that. How many columns has your original dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, i am using `chunksize = 24*batch_size` for each `input` file and `chunksize = batch_size` for each `target` file (every 24 lines in a input file corresponds to 1 line in the corresponding output file). In the original data, the `input` have 2 columns and the `output` has 3. That was done because in my model, the inputlayer is defined like this: `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24,2,1),name='InputLayer')`

Comment: ok, so you can try : `X_train = np.resize(X_train, (X_train.size / 24 / 2, 24, 2, 1))` instead of first break and the same with `X_valid`.

Comment: Right, i am going to try that asap. But, i assume i need to add `try/except` block to both `Y_train` and `Y_valid`? Since both of them can also fall into the same dimension problem.

Comment: I don't think the same problem could appear with the Y since we don't reshape them with `batch_size`.  And if the two `try/except` blocks are passed, i don't  think the 3 last lines will raise exception.

Comment: Oh, the problem appeared. I got this error in `model.fit_generator`: `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 32 input samples and 5 target samples.` `X_valid` got a (32,24,2,1) shape while `Y_valid` got a `(5,2)` shape.

Comment: Maybe this is a more serious problem, because this could mean that you are reading lines wrong and you're trying to train with wrong labels. What is the 2-sized dimension ? Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve ? Maybe you should consider to use the `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()` function : [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).